# Suppress "Member is never assigned to" warning in C#

Tags: c#, inotifypropertychanged, suppress-warnings, reactiveui, callermembername

I have the following code:

```
ViewPortViewModel _Trochoid;
public ViewPortViewModel Trochoid
{
    get { return _Trochoid; }
    set { this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(value); }
}
```

using ReactiveUI INPC support. The compiler is always warning me that `Trochoid` is never assigned to and will always be null. However due to the magic that `RaiseAndSetIfChanged` performs through `CallerMemberName` support, the code does work and the compiler is wrong.

How do I *cleanly* suppress these warnings in my code?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> How to **cleanly** suppress these warnings in my code

An alternative to an inappropriate assignment would be to just a `#pragma`:

```
#pragma warning disable 0649 // Assigned by reflection
ViewPortViewModel _Trochoid;
#pragma warning restore 0649
```

That should work, and it keeps the ugliness at exactly the place that it makes sense to document it - at the field declaration.

If you have multiple fields handled in the same way, you could put them all in the same "block" of disabled warnings, with a comment applicable to all of them.

Whether you view this as "clean" or not is a matter of taste, of course. I think I prefer it to assignments which are only there for the *side-effect* of removing the warnings.

Comment: Though a default assignment is something you might well do anyway. Either way we're saying "we know this is nothing" as of now. Of this, I do like the grouping factor. But, who am I...

Comment: I prefer this because it would also stop a dev (maybe who is using resharper or similar) from assuming the field can be made readonly.

Comment: Can I use SuppressMessageAttribute http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.codeanalysis.suppressmessageattribute%28v=vs.100%29.aspx but I can't figure out how to generate the extremely verbose attr from the compiler warning?

Comment: @bradgonesurfing: I'm not sure that it's used by the compiler - I'd expect it to be used by FxCop etc instead. I could be wrong though :)

Comment: @bradgonesurfing ["You should not use in-source suppressions on release builds to prevent shipping the in-source suppression metadata accidentally. Because of the processing cost of in-source suppression, the performance of your application can also be degraded by including the in-source suppression metadata."](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms244717(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: There's no need to pragma everything! See my answer below :)

Answer (score 7):

Now that every platform has `CallerMemberNameAttribute` support in ReactiveUI, there's no need to suffer the oppression of your Obsessive Compulsive Compiler:

```
ViewPortViewModel _Trochoid;
public ViewPortViewModel Trochoid
{
    get { return _Trochoid; }
    set { this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _Trochoid, value); }
}
```

The other overloads are really unnecessary now, but I leave them in because removing them is a  breaking change and therefore won't be done until ReactiveUI 5.0

Comment: The OP is already using CallerMemberNameAttribute - and setting the value by reflection: "However due to the magic that RaiseAndSetIfChanged performs through CallerMemberName" - I was assuming they didn't want to change how they used `RaiseAndSetIfChanged`.

Comment: If you use the Ref overload, it won't do the reflection :)

Answer (score 4):

You could assign it a default for a reference type:

```
ViewPortViewModel _Trochoid = null;
```

Comment: This works but feels wrong as I overwrite the value in the constructor.

Comment: If you have a tool like resharper, doing this will cause it to tell you that the field can be made readonly, and you'll still have to put a comment to supress that.